# Rails undefined method `model_name' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am having this `undefined method model_name' error` , and I have been trying all the similar posts on StackOverFlow but cannot solve it. Can some one help please.

```
views/modules/new.html.erb

<h1 align="center"> Modules Available </h1>

<%= form_for (@module) do |m| %>

    <p>
        <%= m.lable :module_code %>
        <%= m.text_field :module_code %>
    </p>

<% end %>

modules_controller.rb
class ModulesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @module = Module.new
    end
end

module.rb
class Module < ApplicationRecord::Base
    
end
```

Comment: `Module` is a reserved word in Rails, properly that is the problem.

Comment: There is no method called `model_name` in your code, but there isn't an attempt to call a method of that name either. So the problem is somewhere else in your code.